# Require Blender to update N or T panel

Tags: python, interface

I create a auto setup matcap texture addon and i'd like to know if it should be possible to "require" blender to update N panel.
Got a template_preview and it should be great that it refresh automaticaly.
If it really not possible, is it possible to get the texture list box or did i have to create my own texture list ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Region.tag_redraw](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Region.html?highlight=types.region#bpy.types.Region.tag_redraw) on the corresponding region. The [region type](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Region.html?highlight=types.region#bpy.types.Region.type) of the <kbd>T</kbd>-Panel is `'TOOLS'` and the type of the <kbd>N</kbd>-Panel is `'UI'`.

I.e.

```
for region in context.area.regions:
    if region.type == "UI":
        region.tag_redraw()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, Just need to put "context.'UI'.tag_redraw()" at the end of my execute, Just before "return{'FINISHED'} ?

Comment: added an example

Comment: This does not work for me. My code is running in a separate thread so I used `for region in bpy.context.area.regions:` instead of `for region in context.area.regions:` but it triggers an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'regions'`